# Why are 'table salt and sugar are both terrible candidates for recrystallization'?

Tags: purification, recrystallization

I received a comment on one of my other chemistry [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60323/why-add-specifically-hot-solvent-during-recrystallization-procedures-instead-of)s stating that

> table salt and sugar are both terrible candidates for recrystallization, albeit for different reasons.

Why are salt and sugar terrible candidates for recrystallization?

Comment: What do you know about recrystallization, to begin with?

Comment: Meanwhile, if somebody else attempts to answer this, please keep in mind that my comment implied the conditions of a small-scale home experiment. Industrial conditions can be pretty different.

Comment: I understand the physical principle of separation by recrystallization. I don't know what properties of sucrose or NaCl are by themselves making those compounds unlikely to be purified successfully by recrystallization.

Comment: What are the principles involved, then? See, I need to know what you already know, otherwise how am I to know where to start? Why would a substance dissolve and then crystallize, to begin with?

Comment: Solubility is a function of temperature. I want to recrystallize A from a mixture. A has a higher solubility than the other components of the solid. Hot solvent at BP and volume at saturation of A is added to mixture. A good solvent will have certain properties, especially dissolving the whole mixture at its BP. Slow cooling to form seed crystals of A. Continued cooling favors more A being added to existing crystals of A.

Comment: Good. Now, is that function of temperature the same for all compounds? Obviously not. Look up the solubility of $\ce{NaCl}$ at different temperatures.

Comment: I used Python to plot the solubilities of sucrose and NaCl in water at 1 atm, and I see the solubilities appear to be quadratic functions of temperature with different coefficients.  Sucrose is more soluble and changes solubility 'faster' than NaCl.

Comment: I plotted solubility with temperature, I should add.

Comment: Quadratic or not, it's not that important. Does it change much (for NaCl, I mean)? How much salt would you use per 100g of water, and how much of that would you eventually *lose*?

Comment: Fair enough about the model structure. Extrapolating, if I keep decreasing the temperature toward 0 K I hypothetically expect pretty much all of the salt to come out of solution. More practically speaking, my solvent will freeze well before 0 K. At 0 C I expect the mother liquor will hold onto up to ~35.65 g of NaCl per 100 g of water, which is considered loss if I stop cooling at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solubility of $\ce{NaCl}$ has very poor temperature dependency. If you dissolve it at $100^\circ\rm C$ and precipitate at $20^\circ\rm C$, you'll essentially lose about 35 g to purify 3 g. Even using a fridge, you'll still lose more than half of the product, which is quite a bad business. Industrial process relies on evaporation, I think.

Sugar is another story. It does have a nice temperature dependence, but it dissolves too well, even when cold. Just imagine dealing with that awfully viscous syrup, like molasses. It would take *forever* to filter, and quite a while to crystallize. Industry can handle that, but for home chemistry I'd suggest something more pleasant.

Comment: Haha, reminds me of an experiment a colleague told me about, where students in Bochum tried to create a saturated solution of sugar in water (in a coke bottle). Every now and again, they would drop another two lumps of sugar in but it would just keep dissolving.